# Why template function only base the return type works on C++?

Tags: c++, templates

As I know, overloading functions must contain different arguments(type or count). So I think the template function should not only base on the return type. However the following code works on `GCC 6.3.0`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T add(double a, double b)
{
    return static_cast<T>(a + b); 
}

int main()
{
    cout << add<int>(1.1, 1) << endl;
    cout << add<double>(1.1, 1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Build and run:

```
g++ -g -o test test.cpp
./test
2
2.1
```

Dose the C++ standard clarify this? Thanks!

Comment: It's plain overloading, but when you specify the template parameter then there's no more overload resolution since there's only 1 candidate function.

Comment: `add<int>` and `add<double>` are two completely separate functions, they have nothing to do with each other (the fact that they are specializations of the same template doesn't matter here). So there is no overloading here. Consider them as if they called `add_int` and `add_double`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason you cannot overload based on return type alone is that the return type is not part of a functions signature, unlike the parameter types. Don't take my word for it, the C++ standard says as much:

> **[[defns.signature]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.defs#defns.signature)**
>
> ⟨function⟩ name, parameter-type-list, and enclosing namespace (if any)
>
> [ Note: Signatures are used as a basis for name mangling and
>   linking. — end note ]

But for function template *specializations*, be they generated implicitly or explicitly, the signature contains the argument(s):

> [**[defns.signature.spec]**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.defs#defns.signature.spec)
>
> ⟨function template specialization⟩ signature of the template of which
>   it is a specialization and its template arguments (whether explicitly
>   specified or deduced)

So for `add<int>`, the `int` becomes part of the signature. Not because it's the return type, but because it's the template argument. Same for `add<double>`. And so long as the signatures are different, those can be identified as different functions, and therefore may be overloaded on the same name.

Answer (score 4):

User  [StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817643/storyteller) gave the best straight up answer coming from the `standard`. I would like to elaborate on this by giving a break down example of how compilers treat this:

---

Let's look at your current code:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> using namespace std;
>
> template<typename T>
> T add(double a, double b) {
>     return static_cast<T>(a + b); 
> }
>
> int main() {
>     cout << add<int>(1.1, 1) << endl;
>     cout << add<double>(1.1, 1) << endl;
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Let's see how the compiler will treat this. Before we do that, remember this: `templates` have to be known at compile time and similar to how C++ replaces text with macros and defines it does something of that nature for `templates` as well when they become instantiated.

Your function template has this signature: this will generate which ever function it needs to satisfy `T`.

> ```
> template<typename T>
> T add(double a, double b) {
>     return static_cast<T>(a + b); 
> }
> ```

However in this case `T` is not a part of the signature. The function's signature looks like this:

```
::add<T>(double, double)
```

And since the `templates` `argument` refers to its `return` type as opposed to one of its `parameters` it has no effect here.

---

Let's look at this as if we weren't using templates. For demonstration purposes only: ignore the fact that the following will create ambiguous functions:

```
int add( double, double );
float add( double, double );
double add( double, double );
```

Now let's apply the function calls in your main without the template version:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << add( 1.1, 1 ) << '\n';  // <int> - reminder of original
    std::cout << add( 1.1, 1 ) << '\n';  // <double> -     ""
    return 0;
}
```

Now looking at the code above, you have the same exact function call. So which overload does the add in this case call? It's quite simple; without using a `template` and ignoring the `ambiguity`, the above function would call `double add( double, double )`.

Since the above would generate a compiler error due to being ambiguous, let's go back and apply the `template` to investigate why this ambiguity doesn't happen with the `template` version.

---

> *-Original Code-*

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
T add( double a, double b ) {
    return static_cast<T>( a + b );
}

int main() {
    std::cout << add<int>(1.1, 1) << '\n';
    std::cout << add<double>(1.1,1) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Let's see how the compiler treats this in a step by step fashion:

---

> *-Step 1:* - Name Resolution, acquiring the function signature.

```
int main() {
    std::cout << ::add<int>( 1.1, 1 ) << '\n';
    std::cout << ::add<double>( 1.1, 1 ) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

---

> *-Step 2:* - Calling the function, and creating the function's call stack

```
int main() {
    std::cout << 
        ::add<int>( 1.1, 1 ) {
           return static_cast<int>( 1.1 + 1 );
        }
              << '\n';

    std::cout <<
        ::add<double>( 1.1, 1 ) {
            return static_cast<double>( 1.1 + 1 );
        }
              << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

---

> *-Step 3:* - Performing all of the instructions within the function

```
int main() {
    std::cout << 
        /*::add<int>( 1.1, 1 ) {
           return static_cast<int>( 1.1 + 1 );
        }*/
           return static_cast<int>( 2.1 ); 
              << '\n';

    std::cout <<
        /*::add<double>( 1.1, 1 ) {
            return static_cast<double>( 1.1 + 1 );
        }*/
            return static_cast<double>( 2.1 );
              << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

---

> *-Step 4:* - Returning the result back from the function and cleaning up the function call stack

```
int main() {
    std::cout << 
            return 2; 
              << '\n';

    std::cout <<
            return 2.1;
              << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

---

> *-Step 5:* - Main function is passing the returned results into the stream operators to the standard screen output.

```
int main() {
    std::cout << 2 << '\n';
    std::cout << 2.1 << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

---

And this matches your output exactly!

*-Output-*

```
2
2.1
```

---

I hope this break down helps you to understand `templates` better and to see why there is no ambiguity here as if you didn't use them. The bottom line here is that there is no ambiguity due to the fact that you `explicitly` instantiated the function templates.

Now try to run your program again but this time don't specify a type and let the compiler `implicitly` instantiate the function template. I believe you would get a compiler error!

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
int    foo(void) { return 1; }
double foo(void) { return 1.0; }
```

Then (assume) when you call `foo()`, the compiler would see two candidates for the overload resolution, and has no way to tell which one you want, nor do you have any way to clarify which function you want, so this is forbidden at the point of definition.

But in your code, when you call `add<int>(1.1, 1)`, the compiler sees *only one* candidate as you've explicitly specified the template parameter, which is `::add<int>(double, double)`, so there's no overloading here and therefore nothing goes wrong.

Õ the other hand, the following code will cause the same confusion as the first part of the answer:

```
template int add<int>(double, double);
template double add<double>(double, double);

cout << add(1.1, 1);
```

The first two lines of the above snippet explicitly instantiates the template function for two template parameters, and the last line brings up the overload resolution, which fails because there's no way to differ the two instances. But you have another option to de-ambiguate this function call (specify the template parameter), that's why the top two lines can compile.

Comment: Define(Declare) `int foo(void) { return 1; } ` and `double foo(void) { return 1.0; }` cause the compile error: `ambiguating declaration` even not call one of them. But define `template<typename T> T add(double a, double b) { return static_cast<T>(a + b); }` is OK.

Comment: Your `foo` example is ill-formed at the second `foo` declaration immediately, not at `cout << foo()`, so your explanation is incorrect.

Comment: @sfz That's the point. You have no way to tell the compiler which function you use, so defining like that is forbidden directly, but for the second case you have a chance to make it clear, so it doesn't error out at definition point.

Comment: "the compiler sees two candidates for the overload resolution" - I don't think that overload resolution is the correct term here.

Comment: @Bathsheba I don't know, what else could be?

Comment: @iBug It's a particular instantiation of a template function innit. Note that more than one function is never in a sense available so there is no overloading choice to be made.

Comment: But there are ways to disambiguate `template <typename T>
char foo(T)` from `template <typename T>
int foo(T)` [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5749790138856b8), and it would have been possible to have that for regular functions too (if allowed by standard).

Answer (score 1):

I have try it use the [method from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798325/template-compilation)

First, give the test code:

```
template < class T> T add(T a, T b){
            return a+b;
}

void tmp(){
    add<int>(10, 2);
}

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Then input the commond:

```
gcc -S -O1 test.cpp
```

At last, i'll get the content below:

```
    .file   "compile2.cpp"
    .text
    .globl  _Z3tmpv
    .type   _Z3tmpv, @function
_Z3tmpv:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $2, %esi
    movl    $10, %edi
    call    _Z3addIiET_S0_S0_
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   _Z3tmpv, .-_Z3tmpv
    .globl  _Z3addii
    .type   _Z3addii, @function
_Z3addii:
.LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -8(%rbp)
    movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    movl    -4(%rbp), %edx
    addl    %edx, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE2:
    .size   _Z3addii, .-_Z3addii
    .section    .text._Z3addIiET_S0_S0_,"axG",@progbits,_Z3addIiET_S0_S0_,comdat
    .weak   _Z3addIiET_S0_S0_
    .type   _Z3addIiET_S0_S0_, @function
_Z3addIiET_S0_S0_:
.LFB3:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -8(%rbp)
    movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    movl    -4(%rbp), %edx
    addl    %edx, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3:
    .size   _Z3addIiET_S0_S0_, .-_Z3addIiET_S0_S0_
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

And, we can find two diffrent function signature *_Z3addii* and *_Z3addIiET_S0_S0_*

```
[root@localhost template]# c++filt _Z3addIiET_S0_S0_
int add<int>(int, int)
[root@localhost template]# c++filt _Z3addii
add(int, int)
```

Answer (score 0):

The capabilities of templates in C++ have evolved in a haphazard way since their first inception (which essentially allowed little more than to allow us to write generic container classes). Following this the C++ programming community soon put them to other usages (e.g. metaprogramming techniques).

The ability to instantiate different functions based on the return type alone is allowed since the C++ standards committee (actually Bjarne himself before handing over control of the language) deemed it useful. It is: if only `std::accumulate` worked that way rather than deriving the return type from the type of the variable offering up the initial value!

So useful infact that from C++11 we can even use a *trailing return type* syntax to allow the compiler to derive the return type when it's only discoverable by inspecting the function parameter list and, in later standards, the function contents.

Note one myth that needs to be debunked: in your case `add<double>(double, double)` and `add<int>(double, double)` are **not** function overloads (how could they be? - the names, airity, and parameter types are identical), but rather are different instantiations of the template function.